# Sqlite query (like) not working showing nothing

Tags: android, sqlite

Here I am trying to filter Sqlite database but this query is not working.It's showing nothing . Please help me to find out what am I doing wrong?
Thanks!!

```
public ArrayList<Listcollection> listafterfilter(String s) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    ArrayList<Listcollection> results = new ArrayList<Listcollection>();
    Cursor crs =  null;


    while (crs.moveToNext()) {

        if(s == null || s.length() ==0){
            crs = db.query(CONTACTS_TABLE_NAME, new String[]{C_NAME, C_PHONE , C_TYPE    ,C_ADDRESS ,C_DATE,C_PNAME,C_CDATE , C_MNO ,C_DNAME ,C_DPHONE ,
                C_TSCHARGE ,C_DAMOUNT ,C_FANDSOL, C_TRNO, C_TCRAMOUNT }, null, null, null,null, null);
            Listcollection item = new Listcollection();
            item.setId(crs.getInt(crs.getColumnIndex(CONTACTS_COLUMN_ID)));
            item.setName(crs.getString(crs.getColumnIndex(C_NAME)));
            item.setCdate(crs.getString(crs.getColumnIndex(C_CDATE)));
           item.setType(crs.getString(crs.getColumnIndex(C_TYPE)));
            results.add(item);

        }

        else {
            crs = db.query(true,CONTACTS_TABLE_NAME, new String[]{C_NAME, C_PHONE , C_TYPE ,C_ADDRESS ,C_DATE,C_PNAME,C_CDATE , C_MNO ,C_DNAME ,C_DPHONE ,
                    C_TSCHARGE ,C_DAMOUNT ,C_FANDSOL, C_TRNO, C_TCRAMOUNT }, " like '%"+s+"%'",null, null,null, null, null);

            Listcollection item = new Listcollection();
            item.setId(crs.getInt(crs.getColumnIndex(CONTACTS_COLUMN_ID)));
            item.setName(crs.getString(crs.getColumnIndex(C_NAME)));
            item.setCdate(crs.getString(crs.getColumnIndex(C_CDATE)));
           item.setType(crs.getString(crs.getColumnIndex(C_TYPE)));
            results.add(item);
        }

    }

    db.close();
    return results;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared a cursor

```
Cursor crs =  null;
```

You are trying to traverse or Loop through the cursor when it is null

```
  while (crs.moveToNext())
```

You also have another problem, Even if you fix this there is one more problem.

While looping through the cursor you cannot modify again.

```
 crs = db.query(CONTACTS_TABLE_NAME, new String[]{C_NAME, C_PHONE , C_TYPE    ,C_ADDRESS ,C_DATE,C_PNAME,C_CDATE , C_MNO ,C_DNAME ,C_DPHONE ,
                C_TSCHARGE ,C_DAMOUNT ,C_FANDSOL, C_TRNO, C_TCRAMOUNT }, null, null, null,null, null);
```

You need to declare one more cursor

```
 Cursor crs =  null; 

 Cursor queryCrs =  null; 

   while (crs.moveToNext()) 

     queryCrs = db.query(CONTACTS_TABLE_NAME, new String[]{C_NAME, C_PHONE , C_TYPE    ,C_ADDRESS ,C_DATE,C_PNAME,C_CDATE , C_MNO ,C_DNAME ,C_DPHONE ,
                    C_TSCHARGE ,C_DAMOUNT ,C_FANDSOL, C_TRNO, C_TCRAMOUNT }, null, null, null,null, null);
```